# write a query with eloquent in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

How can I write this query using an Eloquent model? I need to get users who have admin or seller roles.

```
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->where('users.verified' , 1)
    ->join('role_user' , 'role_user.user_id' , '=' , 'users.id')
    ->join('role' , 'role_user.role_id' , '=' , 'role.id')
    ->where('role.title' , 'seller')
    ->orWhere('role.title' , 'admin')
    ->get();
```

Models

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
}


class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Eloquent, and query any entity to return only results where a relationship exists and meets criteria you can use the [whereHas()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method with a subquery.

```
User::where('verified', 1)
    ->whereHas('role', function($query) {
        $query->whereIn('title', ['seller', 'admin']);
    })->get();
```

It is the same syntax in reverse depending on which entity you want at the top level.

```
Role::whereIn('title', ['seller', 'admin'])
    ->whereHas('users', function($query) {
        $query->where('verified', 1);
    })->get();
```